# Need to save JSON in ORMLite and serialize it via Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, ormlite

I have a field on an object that is JSON. I can save this as a String but then when I use Jackson to serialize it and send it up to my server, the JSON is treated as a string and escaped. I'd like to send it up as actual JSON. I've made my getters and setters on the model use JSONObject even though the field is a String, and this makes ORMLite happy but now I'm getting errors when using Jackson for serialization. How can I store JSON via ORMLite and send it unescaped via Jackson (on Android)?

Answer (score 0):

If it as already stored as a JSON encoded String, you do NOT want to use a lib like Jackson -- just write the String as is. Unless you actually need to modify data somehow, in which case you would need to first parse, then modify, and then generate as JSON.

Comment: we're using Jackson for everything else though. Ripping it out just for this one case would be non-trivial and painful.

Comment: You did not read my answer with thought. I did not mean to get rid of Jackson, but rather that no library should be used here: there is no need if all you do is pass JSON data along.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a byte[] and save it as a byte[]. when you pull it out just do `new String(bytes)` and pass it to Jackson.

Comment: but then it's a JSON String still, will Jackson escape it like it is currently? The issue is Jackson sending the json up as {\"key\":\"value\"} instead of {"key":"value"}. If I pull it out of the DB and convert it to a String, won't I still be at square one?

Comment: i don't think it will. the database is probably what was escaping the quotes. i've never used jackson, but if it isn't escaping it everywhere, i don't think it will escape it here.